# How can i add a event function after append a elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I click the button, it will append a div inside body, then, I want to click the div to alert a msg.I tried, but fail. How can I implements with highlight area.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfdWB.png)

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button").click(function()
    {
        div = "<div class='test'>div</div>";
        $("body").append(div);
    });

    $(".test").click(function()
    {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Append div</button>
```

Comment: Please, provide with the code you have made until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should note that when document is ready elements with the `.test` class do not exist (that is why your code didn't work), they are dinamically added. So,  I will do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button").click(function()
    {
        var div = $("<div></div>").addClass('test'); // this is creating div element in dom as jquery 

         // Then attach click function to purpose of its create
        div.click(function()
        {
            alert('test')
        });

        $("body").append(div);// then this is appending created div
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle Playground](https://jsfiddle.net/qkh0gotm/)

Comment: I vote you up, but please, add some explanation that helps him understand the issue he was facing.

Comment: @D.Smania Due to my lack of english i cant fully explain this to him could you edit this for more ?

Comment: I have edited it, but I'm not so good on english also, my native language is spanish. Anyway, I use google translate as help.

Answer (score 1):

One way, is just registering the listener on `click` event after you append it to the body tag, taking care of unregistering the previous clicks events, so you don't fall on multiple clicks events on the same element. Note that when document is ready still don't exists any element with the class `.test`, thats the reason your code was not working. Check next example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button").click(function()
    {
        var div = "<div class='test'></div>";
        $("body").append(div);
            
        $(".test").unbind("click").click(function()
        {
            alert("A new div was clicked!");
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.test {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button type="button">Append new div</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically created elements, use .on, lear more about .on here http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            div = "<div class='test'></div>";
            $("body").append(div);
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.test', function(){
            alert("test");
        });
    });
```